# How to toggle content using markdown

Tags: css, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have a markdown which contains lots of these

````
<details>
<summary>Examples</summary>

```js
const Pall = collectInto(Promise.all.bind(Promise));
let p1 = Promise.resolve(1);
let p2 = Promise.resolve(2);
let p3 = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 3));
Pall(p1, p2, p3).then(console.log);
```

</details>
````

I can toggle examples by clicking on it. But is there any way I can create a checkbox/button to toggle the examples? I cannot use javascript(it's markdown so it is obvious).

SO demands me to do some research before asking so I did it and found aout the following

### What I know :-

- You can open an example by changing the attribute `open` of details to `true`
- You can do it with javscript(`setAttribute`) but you can't use javscript on github repo's `README.md`  due to the fear of `XSS`
- You can't change attributes with `CSS`

This is all I can search for. These points are making me think that it is impossible to do what I want to. But I hope the people on SO will have a way.

Comment: No, you can't do what you want on GitHub's site for the stated XSS reasons.

Comment: Yeah but is there no way I can toggle the examples?

Comment: You would need Javascript and/or CSS for that, and as you note, GitHub won't allow that. So, no, it is not possible.

Comment: But i can use CSS spand you say I can do it with CSS so...

Comment: GitHub won't allow users to define CSS rules for a page just like they don't allow user provided JavaScript to run on the page. You only get what GitHub provides, nothing more. If it doesn't work with what's there, then it's not possible on their site.